# query base on conditions in array of document

Tags: mongoose

db.products

```
{"product":"iphone",
 "people_have_this":[001, 002, 003, 004]} //objectID
{"product":"samsung",
 "people_have_this":[001, 004]}
{"product":"nokia",
 "people_have_this":[001, 002, 003]}
```

db.users

```
{"name":"john",
 "id":"001"}
{"name":"peter",
 "id":"002"}
```

How to get a list of product John has?. What I expected is

```
[{"product":"iphone",
 "people_have_this":[001, 002, 003, 004]},
{"product":"samsung",
 "people_have_this":[001, 004]},
{"product":"nokia",
 "people_have_this":[001, 002, 003]}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the id for John then it's a simple query like this...

```
db.products.find( { people_have_this: "001" } );
```